# Draw more than 4 vertices with texCoord in 2D

Tags: java, libgdx, vertices

I want to draw polygons with more than 4 vertices. The `Batch` class does only define 4 or less. I know for 3D drawing I can use g3db or g3bj to draw each vertex.

Some questions about g3d:

1. Does g3db and g3dj have a performance / speed difference?
2. How can I make a g3db file (I don't mean the fbx-conv).  How do I read/write this file format to make, for example a g2db.

Comment: I don't know how to use it, but you might want to look into g2d's PolygonRegion.

Comment: So... because you don't know how to render a 2d polygon, you want to know to make a 3d model file??? That's like saying *"I don't know how to drive a car, so I want to know how a boat works"*. As for your questions: 1: compared to what? 2: 2d is 3d with z = 0, you don't need a different file format for that. Have a look at PolygonSpriteBatch. This might help you get started: https://gist.github.com/xoppa/2978633678fa1c19cc47

Comment: No the 2 questions are just added becose I wanted to know that too.